# Matrix vector product

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the values of a matrix in a vector:

```
vector<int> m_values;
```

and I want to multiply this "matrix" by a vector, I tried this:

```
 vector<float> Matrix::operator*(vector<float> vec) {
    vector<float> c;
    c.resize(vec.size());
    int counter = 0;

    float i = 0;
    while (i <= float(m_values.size() / vec.size())) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++) {
            if (counter > m_values.size() - 1) {
                break;
            }
            c[j] = (m_values[counter] * vec[j]) + c[j];
            counter++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

But the result seems not correct

Comment: You should probably not pass the input vector by value - you're uselessly making a copy of it; try a const referene to it.

Comment: Also, it would be much better if you could provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the form of an entire small program, not just a single function.

Comment: There is also no hint as to where the matrix dimensions are stored. A matrix has two dimensions (number of rows and number of columns), not only one size. The dimensions influence how matrix/vector multiplication is defined.

Comment: @uneven_mark: I think OP is either not storing those dimensions, or ignoring them (hence my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot multiply a matrix by a vector of arbitrary length.

In a multiplication with the vector "on the right" of a matrix, i.e. `result = my_matrix * my_vec`, the vector `my_vec` must be a column vector whose length is the same as the row length of `my_matrix`; and each element of the result is an inner product of a row of `my_matrix` and the vector:

[image]

You're trying to sort of "pretend" the matrix can be multiplied by any vector, using `vec.size()`. That's at best meaningless.

<sub>PS: I assume `m_valor` is that values vector you started out referring to.</sub>